# How to use ACE editor to edit and save a file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ace-editor

I'm a dummy in HTML.
In my project, I want to use ACE editor to allow the user editing and saving a file.
I succeed to load the file, and to open it with ACE editor.
The problem is how to save it.
For this part, I need your help.

Here is the code I wrote to use ACE.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["save_modification"])){
$file = "./".$_POST["file_name"];
$file_ptr=fopen($file,"w");
fwrite($file_ptr,$_POST["content"]);
fclose($file_ptr);
}?>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="site">
    <div class="header">
        <span>Test</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clean"></div>

<div class="corp">
    <div class="corp_ctn">
        <h1>Edit a file</h1>

        <div id="content" class="paragraphe">

            <?php
                $dir=opendir("./");
                while($file=readdir($dir)){
                    if(!in_array($file, array(".",".."))) {
                        echo '<div style="float:left; margin:0 10px; text-align:center;"><a href="?f='.$file.'">';
                        echo $file;
                        echo '</a></div>';
                        echo '<br/>';
                    }
                }
            ?>

            <br clear="all"/>

            <?php
                if(isset($_GET["f"])) {
                    echo "<h1>{$_GET["f"]}</h1>";
                    $file = "./".$_GET["f"];
                    $content = file_get_contents($file);
            ?>


                    <form method="POST" action="index_select_lua_script.php">
                        <div id="editor" name="content" style="width:100%;height:200px;">
                            <?php echo $content ?> 
                        </div>

                        <script src="js/ace/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
                        <script>
                            var editor = ace.edit("editor");
                            editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
                            editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/lua");
                            editor.getSession().setTabSize(4);
                            editor.setHighlightActiveLine(true);
                            editor.resize();
                        </script>
                        <input type="hidden" name="file_name" value="<?php echo $_GET["f"] ?>" />
                        <input type="submit" name="save_modification" value="Save modification" />
                    </form>
                    <br/><br/>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I save my modification, using the save button, the content is empty.
Please, do you have an idea of how I can do it?

Thank you

Comment: Div is not a form element. You'll probably need another input or textarea that's hidden and when save is clicked populate hidden input with content from div and continue to submit form

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 Filesystem API handles tasks like this quite well now. There are a few ways of capturing the contents of the editor area, and once you've done that you can save it.

Look at something like:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/668351/HTML-File-API-Capability-and-Compatibility

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-an-html5-text-editor-with-the-filesystem-apis

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Can't remember where, but you can ZIP files together using JS now as well, if you so wish.